# How to prevent extremely annoying codes in user input

Tags: php

Is it possible to prevent characters that break the layout? Like this:

̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳
S̳͇͉̩̳
̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳

̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕
̠S̳͇͉̩̳

S̳͇͉̩̳̤͎͍͖̳̙͚̭͕̠S̳͇͉̩̳

Comment: Those aren't ASCII characters.

Comment: Can you be more specific? what php code is generating that? which pagecode?  what layout is this breaking?

Comment: For example, if a user comments exactly that, there any way to sanitize them in the output?

Comment: Well, I don't think that's a language at all. It just falls out of the layout, it shouldn't be over my comment for example

Comment: I think it's a valid question.

Comment: Have you tried HTMLentities() ?

Comment: @Mariano please clarify the question. Do you want to strip all non-ascii chars or just those that might potentially break the layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent it by whitelisting UTF8 chars from a limited range, for example only the latin code points, see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ for the hex values.

Answer (score -1):

before accepting user input, check for ASCII chars then [remove non-ASCII chars](http://www.stemkoski.com/php-remove-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string/) with this PHP code.

Comment: That will render comments written in other languages (or just words borrowed from other languages!) unreadable... not appropriate for sanitizing comments.